Docker Desktop перезапускает только часть сервисов в контейнере
Суть проблемы:
Пытаюсь сделать так чтоб мой контейнер со всеми сервисами запускался при старте Windows, но не смотря на то, что везде стоит restart: always запускается при запуске системы только phpmyadmin, при этом mysql и xampp просто не запускаются почему-то(в логах Docker Desktop пусто, ошибок нет). Если запускать контейнер в ручную то все работает как часы.
Уточнающая информация:

OS - Windows
Использую WSL 2
Файлы проекта находятся в файловой системе подсистемы ubuntu по пути /home
запускаю и собираю проект из терминала ubuntu командами docker compose up и docker-compose up -d --build

docker-compose.yml:
version: "3.9"

services:
  php-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile 
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./apache/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
    depends_on:
      - database-container
    ports:
      - 3000:80 

  database-container:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysql_pass
      MYSQL_USER: test_user
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mysql_db
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: user_pass
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/my.cnf
      - ./mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql:rw"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - database-container
    links:
      - database-container
    ports:
      - "3001:80"
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: database-container 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysql_pass


Вот здесь предлагают явным образом указать сеть для проекта. Пишут, что помогло.

@PakUula, я попробовал - не сработало, похоже ошибка кроется где-то в wls ибо я отключил wls и попробовал то же самое с hyperx и все запускается как надо, но что с этим делать теперь не понятно, если не размещать файлы проекта внутри подсистемы, то докер работает жутко медленно...

Для тех, кто столкнется с подобной проблемой, и кому докер нужен не только для отладки, а чтобы все работало быстро, советую не устанавливать docker desktop вообще, а поставить wls2, и внутри подсистемы linux (в моем случае ubuntu 24.04.1) установить docker, потому что я потерял 4 дня на танцы с бубном и по итогу пришел к выводу, что интеграция wls2 с docker desktop то ли сырая, то ли работает как-то некорректно, из wsl все работает нормально, порты даже не пришлось внутри прокидывать.
